# Sending a list of javascript objects from QML to c++

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, qml

I have an invokable c++ function that I call from a QML file. I would like this function to accept a list of javascript objects (or maps) as an argument. The Qt documentation indicates that javascript lists are translated to QVariantList, and javascript objects to QVariantMap. ([see here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-data.html#qvariantlist-and-qvariantmap-to-javascript-array-and-object), last paragraph of the section).

> Similarly, if a C++ type uses a QVariantList or QVariantMap type for a property type or method parameter, the value can be created as a JavaScript array or object in QML, and is automatically converted to a QVariantList or QVariantMap when it is passed to C++.

Unfortunately, when the argument is typed as a `QVariantList`, `QList<QVariant>` or even `QVariant`(then translated to a `QList<QVariant>`) the length returned is 0. I also tried having it typed as a `QList<QObject*>` and the length of the list can be read, but I can't access the data inside as a QObject* cannot be cast to a QVariant.

QML code excerpt:

```
for(currentLabel = 0; currentLabel<acquisitionsLabels.length; currentLabel++){
    label = acquisitionsLabels[currentLabel];
    link = db.getLinkFromLabel(label)[0];
    structureName="";
    if(link){
        criteria = db.getCriteriaFromId(link.fkCriteria);
        structure = db.getStructureFromId(criteria.fkStructure);
        structureName = structure.name;
    }
    labels.push({
                    "label":label,
                    "structureName":structureName,
                    "moreToCome":currentLabel<acquisitionsLabels.length-1
                });
}
console.log(labels.length);
exportReportFile.printAcquisition(acquisition, acquisitionRenderer.renderAcquisition(acquisition), labels);
```

exportReportFile.cpp excerpt:

```
void ExportReportFile::printAcquisition(QObject *a_acquisition, const QVariant&  a_labels){
    QList<QVariant> l_labels = a_labels.value<QList<QVariant>>();
    std::cout << typeid(l_labels).name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << l_labels.count() << std::endl;
    if(l_labels.length()>0){
       for(int i=0;i<l_labels.count();i++) {
           auto item = l_labels.at(i);
           std::cout << typeid(item).name() << std::endl;
       }
    }
}
```

This version is with the argument being a `QVariant` reference, but I also tried with all previously cited types.

The expected output for a list that is 3 items long would be:

```
qml: 3
class QList<class QVariant>
3
class QVariant
class QVariant
class QVariant
```

and it actually is

```
qml: 3
class QList<class QVariant>
0
```

Comment: try to use const QVariantList & labels instead const QVariant&  a_labels

Comment: Please post only relevant code that could be run. Please remove all unnecessary code, like access to DB etc. Read how to create [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks :) I tried this a few times, with the same result. I'm thinking maybe it has something to do with the type of the `label` that I put inside the JS object ?

@folibis ok, I'll try to clean it up.

Comment: Problem found, thanks : in the QML call of the C++ method, I had 3 arguments, while the C++ code only asked for 2. Sorry for the bother.

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that takes a [`QJSValue`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsvalue.html) as parameter. This way the value is not converted to `QVariant` but the actual JS data is returned. You can then continue doing stuff with that as you please, including the conversion to QVariant, if needed:

```
void ExportReportFile::printAcquisition(QObject *a_acquisition, const QJSValue&  a_labels) {
    // do stuff with it:
    const int length = jsArray.property("length").toInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
        auto arrayElement = jsArray.property(i);
        // now you have the element etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: In the end this was not the problem. `QVariantList`, `QList<QVariant>`, `QVariant`(then translated to a `QList<QVariant>`) all work. The problem was that in the QML call of the C++ method, I had 3 arguments, while the C++ code only asked for 2. I am not sure why an error didn't show up.